# ansible [WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: update_cache

Tags: apt, ansible, warning

I'm not sure why I'm getting this warning. I've already checked the apt module and it says:

```
update_cache 
bool
Choices:
no ←
yes
Run the equivalent of apt-get update before the operation. Can be run as part of the package installation or as a separate step.
```

These are the two instances in which update_cache is present:

```
- name: Install Apache
      apt:
        name: apache2
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

- name: install php7.2-fpm and all necessary modules
      apt: name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
         - php7.2-fpm
         - php7.2-gd
         - php7.2-curl
         - php7.2-mysql
         #- php7.2-mcrypt
         - php7.2-mbstring
         - php7.2-xml
      update_cache: yes
      when: ppastable is success
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this warning?

Answer (score 1):

`update_cache` is meant to be an argument to the `apt` command, but you've placed it as an argument to the task instead.

Remove it from its present position and add it to the `apt` command, i.e.:

```
apt: name={{item}} state=present update_cache=yes
```

P.S. If `update_cache` blows up, the workaround is to install aptitude. For example:

```
- name: Install aptitude on Debian systems (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18987)
  apt: pkg=aptitude state=latest
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: Update apt cache (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18987)
  apt: update_cache=yes
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer! So how can I make sure that apt is updated after adding a new repo? If the update isn't done, then I won't be able to install any packages from the newly installed repo.

Comment: The answer is you use `update_cache`. So there must be something about your question I don't understand.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't read your answer correctly. it's all there :) Thanks for the explanation :)